# How can I inherit properties of multiple object in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am looking for a way to inherit properties from multiple objects. This should be simple but I'm having a slow guy day! Here is what I want to do:

```
public class Base
{
    public string BaseProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string BaseProperty2 { get; set; }
}

public class Base2
{
    public string Base2Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Base2Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Parent : Base, Base2 (this is not correct, of course)
{
    public string ParentProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string ParentProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

The result is that Parent would have the properties of both Base and Base2. I am trying to avoid using an Interface to avoid extra coding to include the Interface properties manually.

Comment: in C# inheriting multiple classes is not allowed

Comment: you have to have base2 inherit from base, or define an interface with these on

Comment: Use interfaces which are workarounds for not allowing multiple inheritance

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i think he already knows that :P

Comment: @CallumLinington may be he forgot as he had a slow day today :D

Comment: What happens if both `Base1` and `Base2` have a `SomeProperty` property? Which one will be used? If you set `Parent.SomeProperty` which one will be set? There is a reason that most languages don't support multiple inheritance

Comment: Yeah, the Interface method just seems to create more work! May be the only option...  One of the perils of C#. I love the language both this has bugged me for years

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The idea of inheritance is to not duplicate efforts.  The classes should not override the base properties

Comment: @CallumLinington yep :)